# Mac minecraft 1.10.2 server io.netty.channel.ConnectionTimeout.....etc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I made a server following the steps to the book several times and whenever I join it just comes up with the error you see below.
I am on a mac and minecraft 1.10.2, my internet is fine and I'm sure that the ip is correct. The server itself is running and is clearly not showing any problems.

[image]

Comment: When you are trying to connect to the server, is it from an outside connection (ie, from school to home) or inside? (ie, inside home to inside home)

Comment: inside home to inside home

Comment: ok, and is it two seperate computers or is the server on the same computer that you're going to use to play on?

Comment: Its the same computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the fix for you, but it's possible that the IP address you're typing in might be might not be correct in this case.

[On research about the IO.NETTY.CHANNEL.CONNECTTIMEOUTEXCEPTION](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228939/51332) the answer is that the minecraft client took too long to reach the server.  Had this been a server on the internet that you were reaching out to, the possible issues would be hard to pin down.  On the other hand, timeout issues are easier to troubleshoot when it's inside the same network (since the travel time is inside the house) and should be non-existent when it's on the same PC as the server.

I would suggest the following to see if this works:

It's possible that you're trying to connect to your server by using a public IP address (usually starts with something that's **not** 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x) instead of a internal IP. (usually starts with 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x).  Since the server is running on the same PC as the client, you won't even need to use the internal IP and instead you can use "*localhost*" as the address. (*localhost* acts by saying, "use whatever my own IP is")

If the connection does not work with *localhost*, make sure that you include the server port (usually *localhost:25565*) and that your AV/Firewall isn't blocking that port.  Once it's working on *localhost*, from there, find what your internal IP is. (<strike>you can do that using CMD and typing *IPCONFIG* to get the "*IPv4 address*"</strike> *Note 1 on the bottom*.)

If that works, then perfect, you can move on to try your public address.  If not, you may need to make port changes to your home router. (and that's a bit too complicated for this answer. :) )

---

**TL;DR**: use *localhost:25565* instead of an IP address since you're trying to connect on the same PC that's acting as the server.

Note 1: What I wrote is correct for windows, but I forgot that this was a Mac issue. As Judge points out, Going to your Mac **Control Panel -> Network -> Preference** will display with your (internal) IP will be!

Comment: Ok so localhost works!!! So I must be using the wrong IP. How can I check where the right one is? Where do I type IPCONFIG?

Comment: I found it in preferences under network! Thank you for your help!!! I was using the router as apposed to the ipv4.

Comment: Good work! :) - Just remember, if you want someone else to join that's outside your house, have them use the public IP (which you can find by typing "What is my IP" on Google. If they're inside, use that internal IP you found! :)